# Synchronization Job between a master database and other readonly databases

Tags: sql-server-2008, synchronization

I currently have a master database which has certain table that are updated nightly.
I also have numerous readonly databases which contains tables from the master.
What I need help with is synchronizing these readonly tables data to the master database on any inserts, updates, or deletes.
The servers may also sit on different servers than the master database but are on the same network.
Is there any way to write a scheduled job which goes and finds all updates, inserts, and deletes on a table in the master database and (using a primary key for the updates & deletes) perform these operatations on the readonly database?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, write an SSIS package and schedule it to run to synchronize the databases.

Comment: Thanks! I'll search google for some tutorials, but if you have any links that you find extremely helpful can you please post them?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jorgepc/archive/2010/12/07/synchronize-two-tables-using-sql-server-integration-services-ssis-part-i-of-ii.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms169917.aspx